# Is there a word for "less-than-yearly"?

Tags: time

is there a single word to describe an indeterminate less-than-yearly frequency?

Consider the following >

A plan costs $100 annually. The user can choose to pay

- semi-annually, amounting to 2 payments of $52 [$104]
- quarterly, amounting to 4 payments of $27 [$108]
- monthly, amounting to 12 payments of $10 [$120]

Now, I'm looking for a word to say that, should they choose **<%less-than-yearly>** frequency, the service will be more expensive.

Comment: "Should they choose **not to pay a lump sum upfront**, the service will be more expensive." Or "Should they choose **to pay a lump sum upfront**, the service will be less expensive". You don't need to think about using only a word related with frequency.

Comment: You could call them *regular* or [*staggered payments*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22staggered+payments%22), or just ***credit***.

Comment: You have to use a phrase; there's no one word that means "more frequent than annually".    Quarterly is not **less frequent** than annually, BTW.`<%less-than-yearly> frequency` A quarter is less than a year, which increases the frequency. You mean `<%more often than yearly>frequency`.

Comment: closest one i could find was "sub-annual"

Comment: Why not *partial payments*?

Comment: No one will understand sub-annual.  Rathony's wording is good.

Answer (score 2):

A single word to express the situation you describe may not exist. If the purpose of your sentence is to emphasize the saving of money by paying annually, why not just say so explicitly?

"It is least expensive for one to pay for the plan on an annual basis."

Answer (score 0):

The data will be featured in a tabular layout with columns for annual and regular payments next to each other.

I will go with @FumbleFingers' label "staggered payments"